# What is a corpus in topic modeling?

Tags: terminology, discriminant-analysis, topic-models, spark-mllib

I am new to machine learning and I am trying to implement LDA using [Spark Mllib](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda) but I am confused about corpus.
What exactly is a corpus of a document? Is it created document-wise or as a whole for all documents?

Comment: I have tried to copy-edit some of the grammar and spelling, but you may want to check some of my suggested corrections. Feel free to edit or revert my changes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus

Comment: Thanks. But I still having trouble visualizing it. Could you please give some example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A corpus is simply a set of documents. You'll often read "training corpus" in literature and documentation, including the Spark Mllib, to indicate the set of documents used to train a model.

Often, corpora are from a particular domain or publication. See for example this [Reuters corpus]. Other common examples include articles from *Science* or `arXiv`, as can be seen from perusing the corpus browsers on [David Blei's site](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/topicmodeling.html).